# MATLAB: Detection of plus/minus signs in vector

Tags: matlab, vector, detection

I have a vector, for example:

```
test = [1 2 -3 -4 -5 -8 1 2 3 -5 -9 -2 3 2 1];
```

And I would like to detect **the changing of plus/minus sign** in this vector. I need to detect only the changing of signs. For example, if the sign changed, so print on the command line: 'Change'.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possibilities to do this. One of them that doesn't involve `for` loops is:

```
test = [1 2 -3 -4 -5 -8 1 2 3 -5 -9 -2 3 2 1]  % Original vector

signs = sign(test);                            % Get vector signs
diff = signs(2:end) - signs(1:end-1);          % Compute difference between
                                               %   successive values
indices = find(diff ~= 0) + 1;                 % Get indices of sign changes
```

The variable `indices` then has the values 3, 7, 10 and 13.

Answer (score 1):

As @lodestar said, there are many ways to do this. If you are looking for displaying something at the command prompt then you should look at [`disp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html). For instance:

```
>> arrayfun(@(x)disp(['Change at ', num2str(x+1)]),find((test(1:end-1).*test(2:end))<0))

Change at 3
Change at 7
Change at 10
Change at 13
```